# SwiftUI Email Text Markup iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, text, swiftui

How do you markup an email address in iOS 15 with SwiftUI so that it will automatically pull up the email app?

It's simple in UIKit with `NSAttributedString` -"example@gmail.com" will be clickable and will pull up the email app with address populated on click.

Can this be done with SwiftUI similar to bold/hyperlink markups? -

```
Text("Link [Click Me](https://google.com")
```

Is there a simple markup for email addresses too?

Comment: It should be clickable already. If not, try `[email](mailto:tcook@apple.com)`

Comment: @aheze perfect!